# Does calling the current method from inside of its while loop end the previous while loop?

Tags: while-loop

i.e will the calling of example from within itself end the previous loop?

```
private void example(Something something){
    while (whatever) {

        if (something==etc) {
             example(somethingElse); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), and no it (usually) doesn't.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy looks like `Java`

Comment: This is called recursion. The loop is in a self recurring state. Without proper end conditions, the problem will lead to stack overflow.